# UglifyJS / UglifyJS2 - How hard it is to decrypt / revert-engineer the result?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation, uglifyjs

Is there any tool already available that could revert the optimized blob back into human readable, easily-understandable state?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the options, most of the useful information is destroyed in the process, but UglifyJS2 itself can re-add indentation and such. However, local variable names, comments, and sometimes (again, depending on options) other things are destroyed.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "the useful information" bit? What kind of information, exactly? Thought the uglification is mainly about name mangling and line concatenation.

Comment: @Kay: Mostly names, I guess. I don't know about UglifyJS since I primarily use Closure Compiler, but Closure Compiler can inline functions and perform other similar optimizations too.